# I can see some computers on the Home Group, but not others

Tags: windows-7, networking, homegroup

Here is the situation. My Home Group contains several computers. Most are running Windows seven, one might be running Vista (I don't use it, so I am not sure), and one is running XP.

In Explorer under the Home Group, I can see all of the computers except for the XP computer, which is, naturally, the one that I need to get to. I have been able to access the computer by manually typing in the computer's name. When I do this, it appears on the left, but still is not listed in the middle with the other computers.

This is still a problem, because I cannot save files to it (I can't manually type an address in the 'save as' dialogue box). Even though Explorer sees it on the left, the computer is still acting like it isn't there, despite the fact that I can see and open files on it.

Network discovery is on, and I have tried refreshing Explorer several times. There is no change. How can I make Windows 7 see the computer?

**Note:** I recently switched to a new hard-drive, which is when the problem started. Previous to switching, Windows 7 had been able to find the XP computer just fine.

Comment: Homegroups are differant from traditional file and print services. Since XP is too old to participate in homegoups, you will not be able to access it quite the same way you would Win7 hosts. Personally I've always choosen to disable Homegroups and to use traditional file sharing on my networks, so that all the differant types of devices are able to participate. They don't always show up in `network neighborhood` (or whatever they call it these days), because I have a number of switches, but I can always navigate to shares via UNC. have you tried putting the unc path in the save as path?

Comment: @FrankThomas As I mentioned, I can't type a destination path in the save dialogue box. All I have are pulldowns. It is probably also worth mentioning that Windows 7 has found the XP computer before - I recently switched to a new hard-drive, so there is likely some setting somewhere that is causing the problem. I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the computer now, after several hours, *does* appear in the center along with the others. It still does not appear in the save dialogue box. In addition, the computer in the next room has also disappeared from the save dialogue box.

Comment: Further comment: After some research, I have now discovered that the problem in the save dialogue box is unique to Photoshop. Both Word and Notepad show all computers correctly. I still do not know why Photoshop cannot see the other two computers, when it could before on the old hard-drive.